# Multi level import of tensorflow modules not working as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow

Consider the following four pieces of code. Among them, 1, 2, and 3 work.
I believe 4 is similar to 2 and should work. But it doesn't. I get the following error:
`module 'tensorflow._api.v2.lite' has no attribute 'tools'`

What is the difference? Is the behavior of a multi-level import different than a single-level one?

1.

```
from numpy import ones
a = ones((2, 2))
```

2. 

```
import numpy
a = numpy.ones((2, 2))
```

3. 

```
from tensorflow.lite.tools.flatbuffer_utils import read_model_with_mutable_tensors
read_model_with_mutable_tensors("model.tflite")
```

4. 

```
import tensorflow.lite.tools.flatbuffer_utils
tensorflow.lite.tools.flatbuffer_utils.read_model_with_mutable_tensors("model.tflite")
```

Comment: Consider this `from time import sleep` equivalent to `import time`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is more a bit of a guess, but maybe someone can confirm or refute (not sure this is the right word) my theory.
At first, the difference between [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) is important. Modules are the normal .py files, where you can find your classes, functions etc. Packages are a way to structure modules, like a folder structure. Packages can have subpackages and can have a `__init__.py` file to mark them as packages and optionally import or declare some stuff in it.

As for your examples:
For 1, it's pretty simple. The function `ones` is in the module `numpy` and can be imported directly. Note that you only imported `ones` and can't use any other functions from `numpy`.
In the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L138) `ones` is actually in `numpy/core/numeric.py`, but it has the decorator `@set_module('numpy')`, which seems to move it to the `numpy.` import.

In 2, you imported the whole `numpy` namespace, and can then call all the functions it provides you. Including `ones`.

in 3, you import through packages and subpackages. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on
> sys.path looking for the package subdirectory.

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/flatbuffer_utils.py), you can see that the structure of these imports actually exists, so python can find it with `sys.path`.

Now for the difficult part, 4.
Here, I'm not 100% sure how python manages imports. It seems that when you call
`import tensorflow.lite.tools.flatbuffer_utils`
it imports the module `tensorflow` (at least for me, when I checked the variables in my IDE), and I could call `tensorflow.__version__` without error.
When I tried
`import tensorflow.lite.tools.flatbuffer_utils as x`
or
`tensorflow.lite.tools.flatbuffer_utils.read_model_with_mutable_tensors("model.tflite")`
it threw the `ImportError` you mentioned. It seems that in this case, python went through the `__init__.py` of these packages one by one and tried to find everything.
In `tensorflow`s `__init__.py` in my virtual environment's site-packages folder is the line `from ._api.v2 import lite`. If you follow this, you get the `__init__.py` for `lite` (for me it is in `venv/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/lite/__init__.py`). In this `__init__.py`, there is no import for `tools` and no subpackage (folder) `tools`, and this is the part where the `ImportError` happens. So it seems that for some imports python uses `sys.path` to find the path of the function, and sometimes it uses the `__init__.py` for it.

I'd love to have a more coherent and satisfying answer, and maybe someone with more knowledge can extend on this answer.